# Finding substrings in a string and assigning associated values

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a reference table that assigns point values to certain strings

```
strings = {'string': ['key', 'box', 'apple', 'salad'],
        'value': [4,1,2,3]}

string_df = pd.DataFrame(strings)
```

I also have a dictionary of product strings, such as:

```
products = {'product_name': ['Apple salad', 'Box of apples', 'Keybox', 'Pear salad', 'Box of key salads']}

product_df = pd.DataFrame(products)
```

What I need to do is count the number of points that are in each string in product_list, like so:

```
Apple salad = 5 (2 for 'apple' and 3 for 'salad')
Box of apples = 3 (1 for 'box' and 2 for 'apple')
Keybox = 5 (4 for 'key' and 1 for 'box')
```

And so on. I have found a method of identifying TRUE or FALSE whether a word in string_df appears in a string in the product name:

```
string_list_regex = "|".join(string_df['string'])
product_df['string_check'] = product_df['product_name'].str.contains(string_list_regex, regex=True)
```

But I haven't found a way of doing this with assigned values and sums. Is it possible to do this using Regex?

Comment: As a first step you may wish to construct a dictionary to speed lookups: `points = { 'key': 4, 'box': 1, 'apple': 2, 'salad': 3 }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without regex, using operator `in`:

```py
m = string_df.set_index("string")["value"].to_dict()

product_df["value"] = (
    product_df["product_name"]
    .str.lower()
    .apply(lambda x: sum(v for k, v in m.items() if k in x))
)
print(product_df)
```

Prints:

```
        product_name  value
0        Apple salad      5
1      Box of apples      3
2             Keybox      5
3         Pear salad      3
4  Box of key salads      8
```

---

If you want using regular expression:

```py
m = "|".join(f"(?P<{s}>{s})" for s in string_df.string)
tmp = (
    product_df.product_name.str.lower()
    .str.extractall(m)
    .replace(string_df.set_index("string")["value"])
)
product_df["value"] = tmp.sum(axis=1).groupby(level=0).sum()

print(product_df)
```

Prints:

```
        product_name  value
0        Apple salad    5.0
1      Box of apples    3.0
2             Keybox    5.0
3         Pear salad    3.0
4  Box of key salads    8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Apple_salad = ("2 for 'apple' and 3 for 'salad'")
Box_of_apples = ('1 for "Box_of_apples" and 2 for "apple"')
Keybox =  ("4 for 'key' and 1 for 'box'")

lst = [Apple_salad, Box_of_apples, Keybox]

for item in lst:
  total = str(sum([int(n) for n in re.findall(r'(\d+)\s+for' ,item)]))
  item = total +  " " + f'({item})'
  print(item)

5 (2 for 'apple' and 3 for 'salad')
3 (1 for "Box_of_apples" and 2 for "apple")
5 (4 for 'key' and 1 for 'box')
```